# Why does WampServer's page show up when I enter "domaincontrol.com"?

Tags: dns, wamp

When I enter this web address `www.domaincontrol.com` the browser loads `http://localhost/`, which is WampServer. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `nslookup`.

```
domaincontrol.com
127.0.0.1
```

It is just set that way. If you have any more doubts, you can try sending an e-mail to admin@domaincontrol.com :-p